# Javascript: How to replace document.all in this case?

Tags: javascript

In HTML:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" onClick="doConfirmCheckAll()"></td>
```

...and in JS:

```
document.all.checkAll.checked = false;
```

I have to replace the construct with something with the same meaning but I cannot use **document.all** (e.g. because of unsupport in IE11).

What should I use? Is `document.getElementsByTagName("*").checkAll.checked` a good idea?

Comment: Is `checkAll` a form element name? E.g., `<input type='checkbox' name='checkAll'>`? Please [edit] your question to show a short sample of the relevant html.

Comment: You can loop through all checkbox and set it as required.

Comment: Your approach using *getElementsByTagName* will not work, though used differently it can be made to work. If you reply to nnnnnn's question a good answer can be given rather than one that "works" but isn't optimal. Note that *document.all* treats *name* and *id* attributes the same.

Comment: sometimes it's id, sometimes name... it's used in many places in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `checkAll` is a `name` attribute, you'd use

```
document.getElementsByName("checkAll")[0].checked = false;
```

If `checkAll` is an `id` attribute, you'd use

```
document.getElementById("checkAll").checked = false;
```

Comment: Thanks! if it's `name`, how can I choose all of them, is there iteration necessary?

Comment: Yes, you will need to iterate them, just like an array.